# C# Background worker label doesn't update

Tags: label, backgroundworker

```
                        if (process.ProcessName == procName)
                        {
                            // Prime the Performance Counters
                            pcProcess.NextValue();
                            cpuUsage.NextValue();
                            Thread.Sleep(100);

                            double cpuUse = Math.Round(pcProcess.NextValue() / cpuUsage.NextValue() * 100, 2);

                            if (Double.IsNaN(cpuUse))
                                cpuUse = 0;

                            System.DateTime newDate = System.DateTime.Now;

                            double memUseage = process.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1048576;
                            string memusg = memUseage.ToString();
                            label13.Invoke(new Action(() => { label13.Text = "RAM: " + memusg + "mb"; }));

                            //Get CPU Usage
                            Int32 usg = Convert.ToInt32(cpuUsage);
                            label12.Invoke(new Action(() => { label12.Text = "CPU: " + usg.ToString() + "%"; }));

                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
```

Everything is working fine, but the label for the CPU usage won't update. I made some checks, and he stops at the code

```
Int32 usg = Convert.ToInt32(cpuUsage);
```

Can someone explain what is going on here ?

Edit:
I may add here this code too

```
using (PerformanceCounter cpuUsage = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "_Total"))
```

Comment: Any reason that you need to convert to an `integer` from a double, since you are simply calling the ToString() method? Remove the `usg` variable and use the `cpuUsage` in your string format instead.

Comment: Thanks I got it, I had to use cpuUse, and not cpuUsage :D My mistake ^^